# RK4 Python Explanation

Tags: python, numerical-methods, ode, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I'd like to use an implementation of RK4 I found online for something, but I'm having a bit of difficulty wrapping my head around the implementations I have found online.
For example:

```
def rk4(f, x0, y0, x1, n):
    vx = [0] * (n + 1)
    vy = [0] * (n + 1)
    h = (x1 - x0) / float(n)
    vx[0] = x = x0
    vy[0] = y = y0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        k1 = h * f(x, y)
        k2 = h * f(x + 0.5 * h, y + 0.5 * k1)
        k3 = h * f(x + 0.5 * h, y + 0.5 * k2)
        k4 = h * f(x + h, y + k3)
        vx[i] = x = x0 + i * h
        vy[i] = y = y + (k1 + k2 + k2 + k3 + k3 + k4) / 6
return vx, vy
```

Could someone please help me understand what exactly the parameters are? If possible, I'd like a more general explanation, but, if being more specific makes it easier to explain, I'm going to be using it specifically for an ideal spring system.

Comment: Why are you using some undocumented code you found online instead of a documented module like [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) or [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html#hnw93)?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the parameters here:

```
def rk4(f, x0, y0, x1, n):
    ...
    return vx, vy
```

- `f` is the ODE function, declared as `def f(x,y)` for the differential equation `y'(x)=f(x,y(x))`,
- `(x0,y0)` is the initial point and value,
- `x1` is the end of the integration interval `[x0,x1]`
- `n` is the number of sub-intervals or integration steps
- `vx,vx` are the computed sample points, `vy[k]` approximates `y(vx[k])`.

You can not use this for the spring system, as that code only works for a scalar `v`. You would need to change it to work with `numpy` for vector operations.

```
def rk4(func, x0, y0, x1, n):
    y0 = np.array(y0)
    f = lambda x,y: np.array(func(x,y))
    vx = [0] * (n + 1)
    vy = np.zeros( (n + 1,)+y0.shape)
    h = (x1 - x0) / float(n)
    vx[0] = x = x0
    vy[0] = y = y0[:]
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        k1 = h * f(x, y)
        k2 = h * f(x + 0.5 * h, y + 0.5 * k1)
        k3 = h * f(x + 0.5 * h, y + 0.5 * k2)
        k4 = h * f(x + h, y + k3)
        vx[i] = x = x0 + i * h
        vy[i] = y = y + (k1 + 2*(k2 + k3) + k4) / 6
    return vx, vy
```